# Determine if string is Date or Number

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to determine if a string is a number or a date.

Here is my code:

```
this._getFieldFormat = (value) => {

  // check if is date
  let d = new Date(value);

  if (!isNaN( d.getTime() ) ) {
    return 'date';
  }

  // check if is boolean
  // isNaN(false) = false, false is a number (0), true is a number (1)
  if(typeof value  === 'boolean'){
    return 'boolean';
  }

  // check if a string is a number
  if(!isNaN(value)){
    return 'number';
  }

  return typeof value;
};
```

It works for a date like: `2016-04-19T23:09:10.208092Z`. 
The problem is that `1` look to be a valid date (`Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)`) and `isNaN(new Date())` is return `false` (a date is a number).

Any idea on how to get out of this loop?

Comment: test any date format or a specific one?

Comment: Any would be better, but if I have to choose this is the time format: `2016-04-19T23:09:10.208092Z`

Comment: Is there a particular reason why this distinction needs to be made? Also, what about "dates" like 2016—are these valid dates?

Comment: I'm creating a component that give a model build a form, and I would like to able to automatically detect the field type starting from the model.

Comment: @GG. Lodash doesn't check string
`
_.isDate('Mon April 23 2012');
// → false
`

Comment: Uh, `"1461113868862"` clearly is a date, isn't it?

Comment: Do you realise that `new Date('2016')` and `new Date(2016)` both produce valid (though very different) dates?

Answer (score 1):

So what is happening is called coercion. Since javascript is dynamic typing when you give it two different types the js engine tries to coerce one of the types into something reasonable or what it thought you meant.

For instance:

```
isNan("37"); is false because "37" is converted to the number 37
```

> isNaN(new Date()) is return false (a date is a number)

It converted Date to a number so this is correct.

> However, invalid values in date strings not recognized as ISO format as defined by ECMA-262 may or may not result in NaN, depending on the browser and values provided

So

```
new Date('23/25/2014'); // NON-ISO string with invalid date values
```

So this will return NaN in all browsers that comply with ES5 and later.

Also to do a stricter check you can use:

```
Number.isNan(new Date()); // This should return true
```

So to recap make sure the date conform to the ISO standard or it will be NaN and use the stricter check. Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that whether `new Date('23/25/2014')` produces an invalid Date or not is entirely implementation dependent (invalid in Chrome, 2015-11-25 in IE).

Comment: Do you mean browser dependent?

Comment: When dealing with dates its smart to use libraries like moment.js. Date formats can change from OS/Browser/Programming Languages Php parses dates differently than MySQL and javascript using - or / can cause problems as well. with momentJS you can do something like moment(myDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY').toDate() and get the ISO timestamp as long as you put in the expected format.

Comment: @sebenalern—no, there are many implementations of ECMAScript that are not in browsers. The issue is that ECMA-262 *specifies* that parsing is implementation dependent (other than certain ISO 8601 formats), so that's what we get. ;-(

Comment: @PatrickMencias-lewis—but regardless, you must know the format to parse it correctly, and if you know the format you can test without a library (though it might be more convenient with one, of course). ;-)

Comment: Okay now I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

In general and from a Javascript design point of view, however, I don't think you can do it by design. Any number between  8640000000000000 and the earliest date in terms of a number -8640000000000000 can be converted to date (represented as time in milliseconds from 01 January, 1970 UTC).

Therefore, any number not falling is this range cannot be a date. And any number falling in range  would be a valid date or a number and you gotta use context to determine if you want to interpret it as a number or a date.

You could however do a naive implementation to test if number is a valid date or not, but that's the best you can do, without context.

Determining whether a date is a number or not can be a bit easier. Because a human-readable representation of date will return `true` by `isNaN()` thereby determining that it's definitely not a number. Then you would go on and check if that string is a date or not, which you already did in your function.